# Google sign-in button not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-signin

I am testing an application with ionic 4 and angular 8 where I have to log in with Google Sign-In for Websites. The application index:

```
<head>
  <base href="/" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <title>Auth</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to put the button on a home page that comes by default in a blank project.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Auth
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</ion-content>
```

I am testing the application locally so the path to get to the home page is http: // localhost: 8100 / home but when I put the button on the index page it appears on the home page and therefore on all pages that are created what is not correct. How can the problem be solved so that the button appears on the home page?

**Note:** The Google Plus plugin is not required

Comment: The title says it is not showing, your description sounds like it's showing in too many places?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're new to `Ionic 4` with `Angular 8`. First of all, you need to know, what the process of login would be, depending on each platform.

- Would you be working with native, or with a browser?
- How do you handle user sessions? Are you using third-party providers?

  - Yes? Which one? Firebase? Auth0? Keycloak?...

    - You should integrate your end API with the third party library
  - No? You manage it yourself then (decoding google token,...)

    - You should manage the authentication yourself with the API

You may then answer these questions before going any fort.

#### Google Docs

As [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) says:

> Before you begin
>
> Before you can integrate Google Sign-In into your website, you must create a client ID, which you need to call the sign-in API.
>
> ...
>
> When you configure the project, `select the Web browser client type and specify the origin URI of your app`.
>
> After configuration is complete, take note of the client ID that was created. You will need the client ID to complete the next steps. (A client secret is also created, but you need it only for server-side operations.)

#### Ionic in browser

With the browser, the login would require some angular package which would manage it, such as [angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login), [firebase with @angular/fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire).

But I strongly suggest you use the `Google Plus` plugin when talking about native platforms such as android or IOS.